# Prove that $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{2i-1}{2i} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z_+$

Tags: inequality, products

Given that $x_n = \displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n  \frac{2i-1}{2i}$

Then prove that $x_n \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z_+$

What I did was take the logarithm of $x_n$, and I arrived at:
$\log{x_n}=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} (\log{(2i-1)} - \log{2i}) $

I'd like to know if I proceeded correctly, and thus would like further guidance to solve the problem. However, if I haven't approached the problem correctly, I'd appreciate hints and techniques that are applicable.
Please don't post the whole answer because I'd like to work this out on my own.
Thanks.

Comment: How do I make the pie symbol appear bigger?

Comment: use \prod instead

Comment: In your last expression, I suppose that the sum starts at $i=1$. Are you allowed to use the properties of the $\Gamma$ function ?

Comment: Yes it starts at $i=1$

Comment: @aflous The sum is not telescoping.

Comment: I'm sure the sum doesn't telescope

Comment: @claude leibovici: I do not know about the gamma function

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507754/induction-inequality-proof-with-product-operator-prod-k-1n-frac2k-1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Prove it by induction and you should show in the inductive step this inequality:

$$\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+4}}$$
which is simple to see it by taking the square.

**Added:** Notice that
$$(2n+2)^2(3n+1)-(2n+1)^2(3n+4)=n\ge0$$

Comment: This makes it really simple. :)

Comment: In the last step where we need to prove that $x_k \cdot \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+4}}$ we substitute $x_k with \frac{1}{3k+1}$ right?

Comment: So nice and simple !

Comment: Since it would suffice to show that the inequality holds when $x_k$ equals that.