# Induction Inequality Proof with Product Operator $\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(2k-1)}{2k} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3k+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, products

I thought I was doing really well and then I spent 90 minutes confused and I am not sure what the next step is.

I am supposed to show:

$\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(2k-1)}{2k} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$

So I did the base case:

$\prod_{k=1}^{1} \frac{((2*1)-1)}{(2*1)} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{(3*1)+1}})=\frac{1}{2}\leq \frac{1}{2}$

Then I got half way through the induction step:

> $\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(2k-1)}{2k} = \prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(2k-1)}{2k} * \frac{(2(n+1)-1)}{2(n+1)}$

So I was okay with translating the product operator for k+1 into familiar terms.

> $\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}*\frac{(2n+1)}{(2n+2)}$

Then, since $\frac{(2n+1)}{(2n+2)}$ must be positive, when I multiply it with the RHS, the inequality will hold.

Now I think I have to start playing with it, until I get$\frac{1}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}$, but all of my attempts seemed rather inelegant. I figured I could just multiply by the reciprocal of $\frac{(2n+1)}{(2n+2)}$, since it's greater than $\frac{(2n+1)}{(2n+2)}$, which would also not change the inequality, but then I'd just have $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3n+1}}$....and I still  wouldn't know how to get it to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3(n+1)+1}}$. While it seems logically clear, that the square root of a larger number yields a larger number, I don't know how to write it in math language. Can someone help?

Comment: Hint: Can you prove that $$\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\frac1{\sqrt{3n+1}}\leqslant\frac1{\sqrt{3n+4}}\ ?$$

Comment: I don't think so. I don't understand how the 4 came into the comparison. I feel like I am missing some kind of step in the process. After multiplying the RHS by $\frac{(2n+1)}{(2n+2)}$, I know I have to get to the RHS to $n+1$ as well, but other than that, I literally have 0 ideas...

Comment: @LisaEver As for where $4$ comes from: note that $3(n+1)+1=3n+4$.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/784760

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is take the square of the both sides of the hint. Since they are positive numbers the direction of inequality won't change then take the power $-1$ of both sides and when you perform the division on the left side you will see that there is an additional term besides $(3n+4)$ which makes it bigger than $(3n+4)$

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\frac1{\sqrt{3n+1}}\right)^2&\le\left(\frac1{\sqrt{3n+4}}\right)^2\\[5pt]
\frac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n+2)^2(3n+1)}&\le\frac1{3n+4}\\[5pt]
\frac{(2n+2)^2(3n+1)}{(2n+1)^2}&\ge3n+4\\[5pt]
\frac{(4n^2+8n+4)(3n+1)}{4n^2+4n+1}&\ge3n+4\\[5pt]
\frac{12n^3+28n^2+20n+4}{4n^2+4n+1}&\ge3n+4\\[5pt]
\boxed{3n+4}+\frac n{4n^2+4n+1}&\ge\boxed{3n+4}
\end{align}$$

Comment: AH HA! Thank you! I think I get it now. So, if  it isn't clear to me, how to work toward getting the exact expression on the RHS, I can take what I expect to get and see if I can find it somewhere in the step where I multiplied the RHS by the $n+1$ from the LHS.