# I need help with this induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I need help prooving this with induction for n greater or equal to 2.

I know what induction is and how it works but I'm having a hard time with this one.

[image: Text]

I know $
\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} = 
(\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac {2k-1}{2k})*\frac {2(n+1)-1}{2(n+1)}$

Then i can replace $\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac {2k-1}{2k} $ with $\frac {1}{n+1}$ since i know it's smaller thanks to assuming the induction property is true.

Wich gives me $\frac {2(n+1)-1}{2(n+1)^2}$ and i need to show this is bigger than $\frac {1}{n+2}$.

This is when I get stuck since I don't know how to do this.

Thank you for your help ! Also i'm not sure if I took the right path.

Comment: It is similar to the upper bound [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507754/induction-inequality-proof-with-product-operator-prod-k-1n-frac2k-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$P(n) = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k}. \tag{1}$$  Then $$P(n+1) = \frac{2(n+1)-1}{2(n+1)} P(n) = \frac{2n+1}{2n+2} P(n). \tag{2}$$

So if the induction hypothesis holds, then

$$P(n+1) > \frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \frac{1}{n+1}, \tag{3}$$

and we wish to establish that $$\frac{2n+1}{(2n+2)(n+1)} > \frac{1}{n+2}. \tag{4}$$  Is inequality $(4)$ true?  Well, if we suppose for the time being that it is true, then it would imply $$(2n+1)(n+2) > (2n+2)(n+1)$$ or $$2n^2 + 5n + 2 > 2n^2 + 4n + 2,$$ which is satisfied when $n > 0$.  So it does seem to hold.  What we can then do is use this logic in reverse to formally establish $(4)$:  We write

$$\frac{2n+1}{(2n+2)(n+1)} = \frac{2n+1}{2n^2 + 4n + 2} > \frac{2n+1}{2n^2 + 5n + 2} = \frac{2n+1}{(2n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{n+2}, \tag{5}$$ and this combined with $(3)$ completes the inductive step; i.e., if $P(n) > 1/(n+1)$, then $P(n+1) > 1/(n+2)$.